# What is the best way to compare between the many prevProps and nextProps in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-lifecycle

The child component is receiving many updated props from its parent component.I want to update the child component if there is any update in the props.Currently,i'm doing it using the life cycle method `componentWillReceiveProps` which is working as expected.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(this.props.scale_length !== nextProps.scale_length){
      const {scale_height,scale_breadth} = this.props
      this.setState({
        torsoScale: new 
            THREE.Vector3(nextProps.scale_length,scale_height,scale_breadth)
      });
    }
if(this.props.scale_breadth !== nextProps.scale_breadth){
      const {scale_height,scale_length} = this.props
      this.setState({
        torsoScale: new 
            THREE.Vector3(scale_length,scale_height,nextProps.scale_breadth)
      });
    }

...
}
```

But,i would be getting 8+ props in the future.How would i proceed with that.Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to set the same state on any prop change

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Nope,state would be different

Comment: If you are doing such a thing at multiple different places then you should think about generalising it or going about the solution in another way.

Comment: in my opinion if you have so many cases, you should break logics in different components. then probably managing 8+ props will be easier

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I would make use of redux for that matter.I just wanted to know is there any other way to do in the react itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to update the child component if there is any update in the props.

This is what React does by default!  You should work with its normal component updates rather than trying to fight against it and decide whether to update things yourself.

You can use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) for this, but there are probably better ways still, like just computing the vector directly in the `render` method.

Here is an article with lots more detail:  https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: thanks. But how can i update the individual state when there is more than 8+ updated props